# Error in match.arg(position) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Tags: shiny, rstudio, ggvis

I am trying to develop a shiny app where there are data inputs on multiple tabs. The content under each tab works fine on its own however when i attempt to combine them into one app I continue to get this error. Error in match.arg(position) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector. My code is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggvis)
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  hr(),
  sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
              menuItem("Import Data", tabName = "Import", icon=icon("list-alt")),
              menuItem("Bivariate Regression", tabName="Bivariate Regression", icon=icon("line-chart")),
              menuItem("Contingency", tabName = "Contingency", icon = icon("table"))
  ))

  body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(      
      tabItem(tabName= "Import",
              sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                  fileInput("file","Upload the file"), 
                  tags$hr(),
                  h5(helpText("Select the table parameters below")),
                  checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label= 'Header', value= TRUE),
                  checkboxInput(inputId = "stringsAsFactors", "stringsAsFactors", FALSE),
                  br(),
                  radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Seperator', choices = c(Comma=',', Semicolon=';', Tab='\t', Space= ' '), selected= ',')
                ),
                mainPanel(
                  uiOutput("tb")
                )
              )),

      tabItem(tabName= "Bivariate Regression",
              sidebarLayout(
                div(),
                sidebarPanel(
                  fileInput('datfile', ''),
                  selectInput('x', 'x:' ,'x'),
                  selectInput('y', 'y:', 'y'),
                  uiOutput("plot_ui")
                ),
                mainPanel(
                  titlePanel("Plot Output"),
                  ggvisOutput("plot")
                )
              ))
    ))


dashboardPage(
 dashboardHeader(title = "COBE Dashboard"),
  sidebar,
  body)
```

and server

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
shinyServer(function(input, output){   
  #read the data and give import prefrences  
  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()}
    read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep= input$sep, header= input$header, stringsAsFactors= input$stringsAsFactors)
  })

  # display summary of table output
  output$filledf <-renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    input$file
  })

  output$sum <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    summary(data())

  })
  output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    data()

  })

  #generate tabsets when the file is loaded. 
  output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(data()))
      h2("App powered by", tags$img(src='Blue.png', height= 100, width=250))
    else
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("About file", tableOutput("filledf")), tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")), tabPanel("Summary", tableOutput("sum")))
  })
########## Data import end #########

    ########## Bivariate regression begin ###########
    #load the data when the user inputs a file
  theData <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datfile        
    if(is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)        
    d <- read.csv(infile$datapath, header = T)
    d        
  })

  # dynamic variable names
  observe({
    data<-theData()
    updateSelectInput(session, 'x', choices = names(data))
    updateSelectInput(session, 'y', choices = names(data))

  }) # end observe

  #gets the y variable name, will be used to change the plot legends
  yVarName<-reactive({
    input$y
  })

  #gets the x variable name, will be used to change the plot legends
  xVarName<-reactive({
    input$x
  })

  #make the filteredData frame

  filteredData<-reactive({
    data<-isolate(theData())
    #if there is no input, make a dummy dataframe
    if(input$x=="x" && input$y=="y"){
      if(is.null(data)){
        data<-data.frame(x=0,y=0)
      }
    }else{
      data<-data[,c(input$x,input$y)]
      names(data)<-c("x","y")
    }
    data
  })

  #plot the ggvis plot in a reactive block so that it changes with filteredData
  vis<-reactive({
    plotData<-filteredData()
    plotData %>%
      ggvis(~x, ~y) %>%
      layer_points() %>%
      add_axis("y", title = yVarName()) %>%
      add_axis("x", title = xVarName()) %>%
      add_tooltip(function(df) format(sqrt(df$x),digits=2))
  })
  vis%>%bind_shiny("plot", "plot_ui")

 ##### add contingency table ########
  # display contingcy table output
  output$foo <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    as.data.frame.matrix(table((data())))
  })

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extra `div()` element in the second `tabItem` in `tabItems` in `ui.R`. Either provide an argument you implied to or remove that div() element. Also, I have added `session` argument to the `shinyServer()` function in `server.R`. After these changes app is running without any errors.

**EDIT :**

You forgot to add one more `tabItem` for `Contingency` in `tabItems()` function. Also, it is always better to differentiate between `tabName` and the title for that tab. And there should be no spaces in the tab name as per my experience, that is the reason why `Bivariate Regression` tab was not working before. It should work fine now.

Updated code:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggvis)
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  br(),
  sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
              menuItem("Import Data", tabName = "import", icon=icon("list-alt")),
              menuItem("Bivariate Regression", tabName="bivariate_regression", icon=icon("line-chart")),
              menuItem("Contingency", tabName = "contingency", icon = icon("table"))
  ))

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(      
    tabItem(tabName= "import",
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
                fileInput("file","Upload the file"), 
                tags$hr(),
                h5(helpText("Select the table parameters below")),
                checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label= 'Header', value= TRUE),
                checkboxInput(inputId = "stringsAsFactors", "stringsAsFactors", FALSE),
                br(),
                radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Seperator', choices = c(Comma=',', Semicolon=';', Tab='\t', Space= ' '), selected= ',')
              ),
              mainPanel(
                uiOutput("tb")
              )
            )),

    tabItem(tabName= "bivariate_regression",
            sidebarLayout(
              #div(),
              sidebarPanel(
                fileInput('datfile', ''),
                selectInput('x', 'x:' ,'x'),
                selectInput('y', 'y:', 'y'),
                uiOutput("plot_ui")
              ),
              mainPanel(
                titlePanel("Plot Output"),
                ggvisOutput("plot")
              )
            )),
    tabItem(tabName="contingency", h2("Contigency Tab content"))
  ))


dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "COBE Dashboard"),
  sidebar,
  body)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
shinyServer(function(input, output,session){   
  #read the data and give import prefrences  
  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()}
    read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep= input$sep, header= input$header, stringsAsFactors= input$stringsAsFactors)
  })

  # display summary of table output
  output$filledf <-renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    input$file
  })

  output$sum <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    summary(data())

  })
  output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    data()

  })

  #generate tabsets when the file is loaded. 
  output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(data()))
      h2("App powered by", tags$img(src='Blue.png', height= 100, width=250))
    else
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("About file", tableOutput("filledf")), tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")), tabPanel("Summary", tableOutput("sum")))
  })
  ########## Data import end #########

  ########## Bivariate regression begin ###########
  #load the data when the user inputs a file
  theData <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datfile        
    if(is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)        
    d <- read.csv(infile$datapath, header = T)
    d        
  })

  # dynamic variable names
  observe({
    data<-theData()
    updateSelectInput(session, 'x', choices = names(data))
    updateSelectInput(session, 'y', choices = names(data))

  }) # end observe

  #gets the y variable name, will be used to change the plot legends
  yVarName<-reactive({
    input$y
  })

  #gets the x variable name, will be used to change the plot legends
  xVarName<-reactive({
    input$x
  })

  #make the filteredData frame

  filteredData<-reactive({
    data<-isolate(theData())
    #if there is no input, make a dummy dataframe
    if(input$x=="x" && input$y=="y"){
      if(is.null(data)){
        data<-data.frame(x=0,y=0)
      }
    }else{
      data<-data[,c(input$x,input$y)]
      names(data)<-c("x","y")
    }
    data
  })

  #plot the ggvis plot in a reactive block so that it changes with filteredData
  vis<-reactive({
    plotData<-filteredData()
    plotData %>%
      ggvis(~x, ~y) %>%
      layer_points() %>%
      add_axis("y", title = yVarName()) %>%
      add_axis("x", title = xVarName()) %>%
      add_tooltip(function(df) format(sqrt(df$x),digits=2))
  })
  vis%>%bind_shiny("plot", "plot_ui")

  ##### add contingency table ########
  # display contingcy table output
  output$foo <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    as.data.frame.matrix(table((data())))
  })

})
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice @Shiva. The updated code makes the app run however the bi-variate regression and contingency table do not show up when i change to different tabs. I want to make each tab work as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! it works perfectly i couldn't be more pleased! Thanks Shiva!

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you! Please upvote and mark as accepted the answer to help others in the future!

Comment: Will do as soon as I get a high enough reputation!